# Jqgrid update a column for all rows

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

I have a Jqgrid table in which there is column `'ord'` or order.
I have update button which when clicked should update all `rows->column 'ord'` with new order value i.e. `var neworder = {"Banana": 1,"Orange": 2,"Apple": 3,"Mango": 4};`

**NOTE:** 
`var neworder = {"Banana": 1,"Orange": 2,"Apple": 3,"Mango": 4};` will not have additional info like weight and quantity; just new order values.

**HTML:**

```
<button id="update">Update</button>
<table id="grid"></table>
```

**JSFIDDLE:**
http://jsfiddle.net/bababalcksheep/Bpk3E/

**JS:**

```
var data = [
    [1,"Apple", "10", "2.3kg"],
    [2,"Orange", "25", "3kg"],
     [3,"Banana", "6", "1kg"],
     [4,"Mango", "50", "10kg"]
];

$("#grid").jqGrid({
    datatype: "local",
    height: 250,
    colNames: ['Ord','Fruit', 'Quantity', 'Weight'],
    colModel: [{name: 'order',width: 10},{name: 'fruit',width: 50},{name: 'quantity',width: 20},{name: 'weight',width: 20}],
    rownumbers: false,
    autowidth: true,
    caption: "Stack order"
});

// How to update col 'Ord' for all rows and trigger sort for that column
$( "#update" ).click(function() {
    var neworder = {"Banana": 1,"Orange": 2,"Apple": 3,"Mango": 4};
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to me that you need just use `sorttype` defined as function in the `fruit` column. It allows to implement any custom sorting order in case of sorting by `fruit` column.

The changed demo you can find here: http://jsfiddle.net/Bpk3E/13/
It uses the following code

```js
var data = [
        {fruit: "Apple",  quantity: "10", weight: "2.3"},
        {fruit: "Orange", quantity: "25", weight: "3"},
        {fruit: "Banana", quantity: "6",  weight: "1"},
        {fruit: "Mango",  quantity: "50", weight: "10"}
    ],
    fruitOrder = {
        "Apple":  1,
        "Orange": 2,
        "Banana": 3,
        "Mango":  4
    };

$("#grid").jqGrid({
    datatype: "local",
    data: data,
    colNames: ["Fruit", "Quantity", "Weight"],
    colModel: [
        {name: "fruit", width: 100,
         sorttype: function (value) {
             return fruitOrder[value]; // return the order from fruitOrder
         }},
        {name: "quantity", width: 80, align: "right",
         formetter: "integer", sorttype: "integer"},
        {name: "weight", width: 80, align: "right", sorttype: "float",
         formatter: "currency", formatoptions: {decimalPlaces: 1, suffix: "kg"}}
    ],
    sortname: "fruit",
    rownumbers: true,
    gridview: true,
    autoencode: true,
    height: "auto",
    caption: "Stack order"
});

$( "#update").button().click(function() {
    fruitOrder = {"Banana": 1, "Orange": 2, "Apple": 3, "Mango": 4};
    $("#grid").trigger("reloadGrid");
});
```

Comment: Thank you. But in this case , user should be see his sorting order.In your example i dont have sorting column.See if user clicks on quantity header then there is no way of knowing what his sort order was as row numbers are static.How can I fix this ? as this seems to be neat method.

Comment: @django: You are welcome! I don't understand what you mean. The order displayed by `rownumbers: true` is exactly the order of sorting. If you want you can add one more column `'Ord'` faving custom formatter. `formatter: function (value, obj) { return fruitOrder[obj.fruit]; }`. See http://jsfiddle.net/Bpk3E/15/

Comment: @Oleg.Thank you. this fiddle is right. Actually let me explain. Rownumbers are static and when i click on quantity column, table is sorted but rowsnumebr dont change, so while sorting other columns there is no way of knowing Apple is on what number in order.In other words Order number should be visible to user so even if he sorts other columns , he should know which row is at what number in order.

Answer (score 1):

I tried this and it seems to be more safe ..

```
$("#update").click(function () {
    var neworder = {
        "Banana": 1,
            "Orange": 2,
            "Apple": 3,
            "Mango": 4
    };
    var dataArray = myGrid.jqGrid('getGridParam', 'data');
    var indexes = myGrid.jqGrid('getGridParam', '_index');
    var rowid;
    for (rowid in indexes) {
        if (indexes.hasOwnProperty(rowid)) {
            var which_row = myGrid.jqGrid('getCell', rowid, 'fruit');
            var newvalue = neworder[which_row];
            // first change the cell in the visible part of grid
            myGrid.jqGrid('setCell', rowid, 'order', newvalue);
            // now change the internal local data
            myGrid.jqGrid('getLocalRow', rowid).order = newvalue;
            // and now sort
            myGrid.jqGrid("sortGrid", "order", true);

        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `setGridParam` to set the new data. After that you may want to reload the grid `.trigger('reloadGrid')`

```
$("#update" ).click(function() {
     var neworder = [ ... ];
     $('#grid').jqGrid('setGridParam', {data: neworder}).trigger('reloadGrid');  
});
```

[example](http://jsfiddle.net/Bpk3E/7/)

Comment: is it possible that i only update ```var neworder = [{fruit:"Banana"},]``` with fruit column only and rest of values like weights and quantity should not be disturbed. I see that t is working but is this the correct method ? If i only trigger updateed value with one cell ? lets say if i have drop down menu in other columns and have made come changes and then click update for fruits only.Will my changes in other cols not be altered ?

Comment: Yes, you could do that.

Comment: No I checked with fiddle.. if I only update with fruits values, weights and quantity are incorrect.

Comment: Sorry, my comment was to short. I meant you could do that, but by another solution.